# How to delete a script in an HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, userscripts

So I am making a userscript for a website, which deletes ads. The website added a script which detects, if the ads have been taken out of the HTML. So to fix this again I want to delete the whole script, but it has no identifiers, so I have no clue how to go about it. Say I have this code:

```
<html>

<body>
    <script>
        if(hasAds) {
            document.write("blah blah blah"); // Act as if this re-ads the ad onto the page
        }
    </script>
    <div id="adsBottom">IMAGINE AD CODE HERE</div>
</body>
     </html>
```

How could I access the script section and delete it?

Comment: Give it an `id`

Comment: @StephenThomas How? I don't own the website I am simple editing it, via a userscript.

Comment: If you know the index to which the `<script>` is appended (i.e. if it's always added first or last in `<head>`) you can use its index to remove it from the DOM.

Comment: @BenM it is the 1st script in a div given the id of "overlay". Do you mind creating the code? I am still learning

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("script")` gives you an Array of scripts. Just iterate through it and locate the script using any heuristic. However, mind that deleting a script does not remove the code, functions, etc.. from the Javascript VM if it has already been loaded.

Comment: So the `<script>` tag is prepended to `<div id="overlay"></div>`, correct?

Comment: If you don't control the script you want to delete, you aren't going to be able to prevent it from running. Even if you delete the `<script>` tag from the DOM, the script may have already executed (depending on what it does).

Comment: @BenM correct it is inside it like this <div id"overlay"><script>//AD PREVENTION SCRIPT</script></div>

Comment: @grahamcracker1234 Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you can presuppose its location in the DOM (and index within `#overlay`), it's relatively straightforward to remove it using [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) and [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes):

```
var target = document.getElementById('overlay');
target.removeChild( target.childNodes[0] );
```

Given the following markup:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <script>/* AD PREVENTION SCRIPT */</script>
    <p>Blah</p>
</div>
```

The above will work (although does rely on the `<script>` being the first child of `#overlay`).

Comment: I have tried implimenting this into my code, but it doesn't work. I also relised that I wrote the <script> outside of the body by accident. I fixed this in the question. Could that have something to do with why it doesn't work?

Comment: @grahamcracker1234 No, the code works correctly (i.e. it answers your question about removing the `<script>` tag from the DOM... You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/yfbyy1ym/1/ The `<script>` tag is correctly removed from the DOM (inspect the element), but the script has already been sent to the JS engine.

Comment: is there a way to direct access it without the index within `#overlay` ? Some other method?